# Example for AWS dynamoDB batchWriteItem on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need to insert multiple items into AWS dynamoDB table. The AWS putItem request works fine, but I can't find any documentation/forum with example for iOS AWS batchWriteItem request.
It probably looks like:

```
dynamoDB.batchWriteItem (request1!) { (output, error) in
                    if  (error == nil ) {
           
        }
        else {
            if error?.localizedDescription.range(of: "offline") != nil {
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Can please somebody give an example how I assemble a "request1"? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link to the official documentation of the AWS SDK for iOS for AWS DynamoDB service: [AWS SDK for iOS - AWSDynamoDB Reference](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/AWSDynamoDB/index.html)

Here is the link to the AWS DynamoDB BatchWriteItem operation from the above documentation: [AWS SDK for iOS - AWS DynamoDB BatchWriteItem](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/AWSDynamoDB/Classes/AWSDynamoDB.html#/c:objc(cs)AWSDynamoDB(im)batchWriteItem:)

Swift Declaration Example:

```
func batchWriteItem(_ request: AWSDynamoDBBatchWriteItemInput) -> Any!
```

More details on `AWSDynamoDBBatchWriteItemInput` can be found here: [AWS SDK for iOS - AWS DynamoDB BatchWriteItemInput](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/AWSDynamoDB/Classes/AWSDynamoDBBatchWriteItemInput.html#/c:objc(cs)AWSDynamoDBBatchWriteItemInput(py)requestItems)

Comment: Thanks! Is anywhere is example how can I write AWSDynamoDBBatchWriteItemInput?

Comment: See this: https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/AWSDynamoDB/Classes/AWSDynamoDBBatchWriteItemInput.html#/c:objc(cs)AWSDynamoDBBatchWriteItemInput(py)requestItems

Comment: @tatiana_c, If you liked the answer and it worked for you, kindly approve it and upvote it as well as recommended by Stack Overflow.